# How to make a wrapper for \input

Tags: macros, input

I would like to make a wrapper for `\input` to include TikZ figures. I have tried something like this:

```
\newcommand{\inputtikz}[1]{%
\tikzsetnextfilename{#1}
\input{figures/{#1}.tikz}
}
```

but with this construction I get:

> LaTeX Error: File `myFigure.tikz' not found.

What is the right way to do something like this?

Does somebody know of any good tutorials or other reading material on LaTeX macros?

Comment: presumably you want `{figures/#1.tikz}` assuming you have given .tiz extensions to your files. (no `{}` around `#1`) you also want `%` at the ends of those lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `{figures/#1.tikz}` assuming you have given `.tikz` extensions to your files. (No `{}` around `#1`) you also want `%` at the ends of those lines.

As you had it it was looking for files with names `{myFigure}.tkz`

Answer (score 2):

This is not wrapper problem, this is only misunderstandning, how the braces `{}` work. I would to add a short summary about `\input` and braces:

- `\input` as TeX primitive in the original TeX and pdfTeX accepts only the file name **without braces** separated  by space or another primitive. Example: `\input file` or `\input file\relax`.
- LaTeX redefines the `\input` primitive as a macro with one parameter. This parameter can be enclosed by braces but it need not. Example: `\input {file}` or `\input file`. The two wariants of scanning the parameter is implemented by `\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@iinput\@@input` where `\@@input` is the primitive `\input` in the LaTeX kernel.
- LuaTeX implements extension to the `\input` primitive in order to user can use filenames with spaces. This extension allows to use braces as a separator. Examples: `\input file` or `\input {file}` or `\input {filename with spaces}`.
- XeTeX uses another syntax for filename with spaces: user can enlose it by `"..."`. Example: `\input "filename with spaces"`.

Result: When you use `\input {filename}` outside LaTeX and outside LuaTeX then you get the error message: `I can't find file {filename}`. Really, TeX is trying to find the filename including braces.

Comment: all true but not actually related to the question as this _is_ in latex but the braces causing the problem were not at the outer level argument braces for `\input` but the braces around the part of the filename passed as `#1`.

Comment: I know that here were second internal pair of braces as a problem of this thread. But it motivated me to write this summary because many users don't know the whole braces story.